# issue getting sound to be played in playn

Tags: audio, playn

i had a sound which was a .wav file.then i converted it into mp3 and tried to play sound like this:

```
Sound mySound = assets().getSound("sound/mysound");
sound.play();
```

i got the following exception in first line itself:

java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:449)
    at playn.java.JavaSound.init(JavaSound.java:91)
    at playn.java.JavaSound.access$000(JavaSound.java:31)
    at playn.java.JavaSound$1.run(JavaSound.java:44)
    at playn.java.JavaAssets.doResourceAction(JavaAssets.java:49)
    at playn.java.JavaSound.(JavaSound.java:42)
    at playn.java.JavaAudio.createSound(JavaAudio.java:28)
    at playn.java.JavaAssets.doGetSound(JavaAssets.java:114)
    at playn.core.AbstractAssets.getSound(AbstractAssets.java:49)

I searched a lot but not getting any solution.Any help!!!!

Comment: Obvious question first: is the name of your sound file mysound or mysound.mp3?

Comment: If nothing helps you may aswell try to use sound/mysound.mp3 instead. Just a wild guess though.

Comment: @domenukk thanks but it will throw file not found exception in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of PlayN, but a problem of OpenJDK.

Using Oracle's JDK fixes the problem. Download and install it and be sure that maven knows the path to the JDK. Setting JAVA_HOME to the location of Oracle's JDK on yout drive should do the trick.

Type the following in the console to see which JDK is used:

```
mvn -v
```